# probability of random walk being equal to its running maximum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

For a Brownian process, the probability of being equal to the running maximum is zero, as in the related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075567/probability-of-a-brownian-motion-being-equal-to-the-running-maximum). For the discrete case, what is the probability that the current random walk value at step $N$ equal to its running maximum? 
$$\mathbb{P}\bigg\{(S_n = \sum_{j = 1}^{j=n} Z_j) = \max_{0\leq t\leq n}(S_t)\bigg\}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume a simple random walk. If we reverse the walk by taking $S'_k = S_N-S_N$, we still have a simple random walk, and the condition "$S$ is at its maximum at $N$" becomes "$S'$ is non-negative". We have reduced the problem to computing $\Pr(S \geq 0,\  \forall 0\leq k \leq N)$. The number of random walks with $N$ steps is $2^N$, the  number $P_N$ of random walks  with $N$ steps who stays non-negative can be computed by decomposing on the number of pluses $p$ and minuses $q$ and using the ballot theorem with ties (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed)

$$P_N = \sum_{q+p =N, q\leq p} \binom N q \frac{p+1-q}{p+1} = \sum_{q\leq \lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \frac {N-2q+1}{N-q+1} \binom N q = \sum_{q\leq \lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \frac {N+1-2q}{N+1} \binom {N+1} q = \sum_{q\leq \lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \binom {N+1} q -2 \sum_{q\leq \lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \frac {q}{N+1} \binom {N+1} q = \sum_{q\leq \lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \binom {N+1} q -2 \sum_{q\leq \lfloor N/2 \rfloor}  \binom {N} {q-1}$$

When $N$ is even, this is equal to $P_N = 2^{N} -2(2^{N-1} - \binom {N}{N/2}/2) =\binom {N}{N/2}$.

When $N$ is odd, this is $P_N = 2^N -\binom {N+1}{(N+1)/2}/2 -2(2^{N-1} - \binom {N}{(N-1)/2}) = 2\binom {N}{(N-1)/2} - \binom {N+1}{(N+1)/2}/2 = \binom {N}{(N-1)/2}$.

We can regroup both cases and obtain $P_N = \binom N {\lfloor N/2\rfloor}$, so the probability is $\frac 1{2^N} \binom N {\lfloor N/2\rfloor}$. It goes to $0$ when $N$ is large, which is consistent with the behavior of the brownian motion.